# Python Merging data from two sources - type error

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to take an Excel file and add some columns from the file to an existing dictionary.  The dictionary is created by a product API, so I'm stuck with the formats I have.

The error message:

```
File "C:\Users\me\RISC.py", line 143, in <listcomp>
    devices=[x for x in assets  if x['data'] 
['identifying_ip']==CMDB_device[ip_col]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is the calling code:

```
    CMDBlist=self._csv_dict_list(CMDBfile) #imports .csv as ordered dict
    for CMDB_device in CMDBlist:           
        assets=device_list['assets'] #a dictionary that includes a list of devices
        devices=[x for x in assets  if x['data']['identifying_ip']==CMDB_device[ip_col]]
        if devices.length()>0: # We matched on IP...do work
```

Sample of data Structure for device_list

```
{
"assets": [
  {
    "data": {
      "deviceid": 12581177603741,
      "devicetype": "Generic SNMP Device",
      "hostname": "myhost",
      "identifying_ip": "10.1.2.3",
      "ips": [
        {
          "ip": "10.1.2.3"
        }
      ],
    "scantime": "1531184292"
    },
    ...
```

My eyes just may be getting blurry from looking at this too long.  Any ideas on where I'm messing this up?

Comment: What is `ip_col`? Something in that line is not what you think is it. Easiest way to find out which is to catch the exception and print everything relevant.

Comment: ip_col='IP Address'  this is the header of the IP Address column in the .csv import.  The import is done with csv.DictReader

Comment: Does `CMDB_device[ip_col]]` need to be:  `CMDB_device['ip_col']]` ?  Hard for me to tell w/o knowing the data or all the code around, but figured maybe?

Comment: ip_col is a parameter to let this method know the name of the column containing the IP Address.  I hard-coded it with the string 'IP Address'.  Nothing changed.

Comment: I found some problems with the Excel input data.  Had some CRLF inside cells that was messing up some records.  Still have problems.  Here is the start of the ordered Dict:  [OrderedDict([('\ufeffName', ''), ('Manufacturer', ''), ('Model ID', 'Unknown'), ('Operating System', ''), ('OS Version', ''), ('Description', 'This CI was retired...'), ('IP Address', '')...

Answer (score 0):

Well, @glibdud was correct.  Something was not as it seemed.  In this case the API I was calling to get the dict would collect data in different ways.  If it used 2 different methods and discovered the same device, I would get a record for each in list format.  If it discovered one I get a dict.  (Someone should ask them why they don't believe in lists with one item.  My favorite to-do lists are [] and lists with only one item.)